# On Oracle Discoverer, sum a group of accounts to be added in only one account

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new here, and new in SQL

I am trying to reach something through discoverer report, I want to sum all P&L transactions related to previous years and adding it to the retained earning account without any need to make a retained earning entry

I tried using this

```
CASE WHEN ( Main Acnt Code = 2220000 AND Td Dept Code = 'ACT' )
THEN SUM(Td Doc Amt)+sum(CASE WHEN ( Main Acnt Code >= 3100000 AND Main Acnt Code <= 4999999 )
THEN SUM(Balance-YTD VAL)
ELSE 0 END
ELSE CASE WHEN Main Acnt Code >= 3100000
THEN 0 ELSE Balance-YTD VAL END END
```

Note:

2220000 = "Retained earning account"

3100000 to 4999999 = P&L account

'**SUM(Balance-YTD VAL)**': **Balance** and **YTD VAL** are 2 newly created columns To calculate the "opening balance"

**'Balance'=** the sum of all transactions since the beginning

**'YTD VAL'=** The sum of 2020 transactions only

The problem that it gives me a message similar to **"Error in Formula - Nested aggregated functions are not allowed"**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested aggregated function are quickly found if you format your formula a bit

```
CASE WHEN ( Main Acnt Code = 2220000 AND Td Dept Code = 'ACT' ) 
THEN SUM(Td Doc Amt)+ sum(CASE WHEN ( Main Acnt Code >= 3100000 AND Main Acnt Code <= 4999999 ) 
                       !  THEN SUM(Balance-YTD VAL) ELSE 0 END 
                       !       !
```

despite of missing closing bracklet and column names containing spaces..

Here are examples of valid usage of aggregated function, that should inspire you to get the result that you vaguely described:

```
select 
  sum(CASE WHEN ( Main_Acnt_Code >= 3100000 AND Main_Acnt_Code <= 4999999 ) 
           THEN (Balance-YTD_VAL) ELSE 0 END)  P_n_L,
  sum(CASE WHEN ( Main_Acnt_Code = 2220000 AND Td_Dept_Code = 'ACT' ) 
           THEN  Td_Doc_Amt ELSE 0 END) as Retained_earning_account
from tab;
```

Adjust the WHEN predicates as required and finally add the two parts...